# cygwin make not found, but installed

Tags: windows, makefile, terminal, cygwin

I did install the 'make' package from Devel and I can see the .exe file in C:\cygwin64\bin

However I still get this: 
make: C:/Program: Command not found

Comment: `makefile` flag is irrelevant I reckon.

Comment: Intall Cygwin (downloaded setup-x86_64.exe) with the folwing comand: 

./setup-x86_64.exe -B --packages=binutils,dos2unix,curl,cygwin32-gcc-g++,gcc-g++,git,gmp,libffi-devel,libgmpdevel,make,nano,openssh,openssl,libcrypt-devel,libssl-devel,python37-crypto,python37-paramiko,python37,python37devel,python37-openssl,python37-pip,python37-setuptools,automake

Answer (score 1):

Your using widows so you have to add The path:

> C:\cygwin64\bin

To your windows PATH variables
To execute a command from this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of `C:\cygwin64\bin` to the environment variables. In windows 10,

[image]

[image]

[image]